# elementorpage builder is not updated

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[It doesn't update when I work on the elementor page builder. I deleted my browser cache and talked to the hosting provider, there is no problem with hosting. Microsoft Edge, chrome, and opera are all browsers used, on different devices use, but one problem is showing again and again. What is the main problem? How can I solve it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpoDe.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of various reasons.
Add this code to your wp-config.php file and check your debug log to find if there is any other error causing the problem.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You can check out the official documentation from this link
[Elementor Updating Issue](https://elementor.com/help/update-issues/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).